# Blocking all RIPE Addresses in Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ddos, ipv4, ip-blocking

Our datacenter has recommended we block all RIPE IP Addresses on one of our machines. It is constantly being DDoS Attacked everytime the null routes are lifted, so I am not sure how this would help, but am more than willing to try anything now.

I couldn't find much information on it from a Google search, but how can we block all RIPE IP Ranges? Preferably I wouldn't even mind blocking all Ranges that were not US Based since that is the only target we traffic, but this is probably too difficult.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Do you mean to drop them at the server? Unless the problem is that you're replying to them, how would that help? They'll still consume the same amount of inbound bandwidth?

Comment: Yeah dropping them at the server. Game Servers run on this machine, so this would stop the attackers being able to query them to see if they are running. Atleast, that is my assumption as to why this was suggested to us by the DC.

Comment: Game servers?  Like.. UT2k4?  This (and a bunch of other) server has a vulnerability in the query protocol that allows it to be used for DRDOS attacks.  There's no real way to can block these, and there's really not a whole lot you can easily do.

Comment: Game Servers like all srcds games, etc. The actual machines are being DDoS attacked, not the exploit allowing the game servers to be turned into a DDoS attacker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two choices. You can block the incoming packets or you can block the replies. Generally, it's more efficient to block the replies because you can just do that with a route. But you can filter the inbound packets in your firewall.

Here are the [networks you need to block](http://www.ripe.net/ripe/docs/ripe-510), arranged as CIDR blocks:

> 2/8, 5/8, 24/8, 31/8, 37/8, 46/8, 62/8, 77/8, 78/7, 80/7. 82/8, 83/8, 84/6, 88/7, 90/8, 91/8, 92/6, 109/8, 128/6, 132/8, 134/7, 136/6, 140/7, 143/8, 144/4, 160/5, 168/6, 176/8, 178/8, 185/8, 188/8, 192/6, 196/8, 198/7, 212/7, 217/8.

Triple check everything!

Answer (score 2):

RIPE NCC addresses list, and formatting for IPSET and Wireshark / tcpdump

RIPE NCC covers Europe, the Middle East, and Central Asia

This list will change with passage of time.  So verify with the authoritative sources.
https://www.iana.org/numbers
https://www.arin.net/

Server is much "happier" with RIPE blocked.

Other regions can be blocked in the same manner.

Those wishing to access from a blocked region can do so by using a VPN service hosted in an unblocked region.

Wireshark / tcpdump capture filter:

> To create a Wireshark / tcpdump capture filter from the address set:
>   1) Remove commented lines
>   2) Replace ".0.0.0/8", ".0.0/16", and ".0/24" with ""
>   3) Replace newline with " or " (remove the last / trailing one)
>   4) Use the addresses string in capture filter. ex: "ip and net (place the addresses sting here)"

iptables:

```
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m set --match-set RIPE src -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -m set --match-set RIPE dst -j DROP
```

ipset:

```
create RIPE hash:net family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 2048
#("counters" and/or "comments" options can be added)
#(prefix each address line below with "add RIPE " ipset command; except those that are commented out)

#
# RIPE Allocated    2018-09-18
#
2.0.0.0/8
5.0.0.0/8
31.0.0.0/8
37.0.0.0/8
46.0.0.0/8
62.0.0.0/8
77.0.0.0/8
78.0.0.0/8
79.0.0.0/8
80.0.0.0/8
81.0.0.0/8
82.0.0.0/8
83.0.0.0/8
84.0.0.0/8
85.0.0.0/8
86.0.0.0/8
87.0.0.0/8
88.0.0.0/8
89.0.0.0/8
90.0.0.0/8
91.0.0.0/8
92.0.0.0/8
93.0.0.0/8
94.0.0.0/8
95.0.0.0/8
109.0.0.0/8
176.0.0.0/8
178.0.0.0/8
185.0.0.0/8
193.0.0.0/8
194.0.0.0/8
195.0.0.0/8
212.0.0.0/8
213.0.0.0/8
217.0.0.0/8
#
# RIPE Legacy   2018-09-18
#
25.0.0.0/8
51.0.0.0/8
141.0.0.0/8
145.0.0.0/8
151.0.0.0/8
188.0.0.0/8
53.0.0.0/8
57.0.0.0/8
#
# RIPE from Recovered IP Pool   2019-03-01
#
45.8.0.0-45.15.255.255
45.65.64.0-45.65.127.255
45.66.0.0-45.67.255.255
45.80.0.0-45.95.255.255
45.128.0.0-45.159.255.255
139.28.0.0-139.28.255.255
147.78.0.0-147.78.255.255
152.89.0.0-152.89.255.255
160.19.92.0-160.19.95.255
160.19.180.0-160.19.183.255
160.20.96.0-160.20.103.255
160.20.108.0-160.20.111.255
160.20.144.0-160.20.159.255
160.20.214.0-160.20.215.255
160.20.229.0-160.20.229.255
160.20.248.0-160.20.249.255
160.202.16.0-160.202.31.255
160.238.21.0-160.238.21.255
160.238.36.0-160.238.39.255
160.238.52.0-160.238.55.255
160.238.60.0-160.238.61.255
160.238.96.0-160.238.99.255
160.238.112.0-160.238.127.255
162.12.200.0-162.12.207.255
192.42.65.0-192.42.65.255
192.54.244.0-192.54.244.255
192.70.192.0-192.70.199.255
192.83.216.0-192.83.216.255
192.94.78.0-192.94.78.255
192.135.100.0-192.135.100.255
192.140.2.0-192.140.3.255
192.144.0.0-192.144.63.255
192.144.75.0-192.144.75.255
192.145.0.0-192.145.127.255
192.145.224.0-192.145.227.255
192.172.232.0-192.172.232.255
192.188.248.0-192.188.248.255
192.251.230.0-192.251.230.255
204.11.0.0-204.11.3.255
204.48.32.0-204.48.33.255
205.211.83.0-205.211.83.255
#
# AFRINIC Legacy administered by RIPE NCC
#
# NET 154
154.8.0.0/19
154.8.32.0/20
154.8.64.0/18
154.14.0.0/16
154.15.0.0/16
154.32.0.0/16
# NET 196
196.1.3.0/24
196.1.5.0/24
196.1.6.0/24
196.1.64.0/22
196.1.69.0/24
196.1.70.0/24
196.2.4.0/24
196.2.5.0/24
196.2.6.0/24
196.2.7.0/24
196.3.66.0/24
196.3.67.0/24
196.3.68.0/22
196.3.91.0/24
196.15.32.0/19
#
# APNIC Legacy administered by RIPE NCC
#
# NET 43
43.225.112.0/22
43.251.160.0/22
# NET 150
150.106.0.0/16
150.107.200.0/22
150.112.0.0/16
150.128.0.0/16
150.129.8.0/22
150.132.0.0/16
150.140.0.0/16
150.145.0.0/16
150.146.0.0/16
150.175.0.0/16
150.178.0.0/16
150.204.0.0/16
150.205.0.0/16
150.213.0.0/16
150.214.0.0/16
150.217.0.0/16
150.227.0.0/16
150.236.0.0/16
150.237.0.0/16
150.241.0.0/16
150.244.0.0/16
150.251.0.0/16
150.254.0.0/16
# NET 153
153.1.0.0/16
153.5.0.0/16
153.15.0.0/16
153.17.0.0/16
153.19.0.0/16
153.88.0.0/16
153.92.0.0/16
153.93.0.0/16
153.94.0.0/16
153.95.0.0/16
153.96.0.0/16
153.97.0.0/16
153.98.0.0/16
153.100.0.0/16
153.108.0.0/16
153.109.0.0/16
153.110.0.0/16
153.112.0.0/16
# NET 163
163.1.0.0/16
163.3.0.0/16
163.5.0.0/16
163.9.0.0/16
163.34.0.0/16
163.62.0.0/16
163.64.0.0/16
163.66.0.0/16
163.67.0.0/16
163.68.0.0/16
163.70.0.0/16
163.73.0.0/16
163.76.0.0/16
163.96.0.0/16
163.100.0.0/16
163.102.0.0/16
163.103.0.0/16
163.104.0.0/16
163.107.0.0/16
163.108.0.0/16
163.109.0.0/16
163.112.0.0/16
163.115.0.0/16
163.116.0.0/16
163.117.0.0/16
163.119.0.0/16
163.156.0.0/16
163.157.0.0/16
163.158.0.0/16
163.159.0.0/16
163.160.0.0/16
163.161.0.0/16
163.162.0.0/16
163.163.0.0/16
163.164.0.0/16
163.165.0.0/16
163.166.0.0/16
163.167.0.0/16
163.168.0.0/16
163.169.0.0/16
163.170.0.0/16
163.171.0.0/16
163.172.0.0/16
163.173.0.0/16
163.174.0.0/16
163.175.0.0/16
163.242.0.0/16
# NET 171
171.16.0.0/16
171.17.0.0/16
171.18.0.0/16
171.19.0.0/16
171.20.0.0/16
171.21.0.0/16
171.22.0.0/16
171.23.0.0/16
171.24.0.0/16
171.25.0.0/16
171.26.0.0/16
171.27.0.0/16
171.28.0.0/16
171.31.0.0/16
171.32.0.0/16
171.33.0.0/16
#
# Early Registrations, Transferred to RIPE NCC (from ARIN)
#
# NET 13
13.116.0.0/14
13.120.0.0/14
13.140.0.0/14
13.168.0.0/13
13.176.0.0/13
13.240.0.0/14
# NET 45
#45.8.0.0/13
#45.66.0.0/15
#45.80.0.0/12
#45.128.0.0/11
# NET 54
54.36.0.0/15
54.38.0.0/16
# NET 128
128.0.0.0/16
128.7.0.0/16
128.16.0.0/16
128.39.0.0/16
128.40.0.0/15
128.45.0.0/16
128.65.0.0/16
128.66.0.0/16
128.67.0.0/16
128.68.0.0/16
128.69.0.0/16
128.70.0.0/16
128.71.0.0/16
128.72.0.0/16
128.73.0.0/16
128.74.0.0/16
128.75.0.0/16
128.76.0.0/16
128.77.0.0/16
128.78.0.0/16
128.79.0.0/16
128.86.0.0/15
128.93.0.0/16
128.98.0.0/16
128.116.128.0/17
128.124.0.0/16
128.127.0.0/16
128.130.0.0/15
128.139.0.0/16
128.140.0.0/16
128.141.0.0/16
128.142.0.0/16
128.168.0.0/16
128.176.0.0/16
128.178.0.0/15
128.199.0.0/16
128.204.0.0/16
128.214.0.0/16
128.232.0.0/16
128.234.0.0/16
128.240.0.0/16
128.243.0.0/16
128.246.0.0/16
# NET 129
129.11.0.0/16
129.12.0.0/15
129.16.0.0/16
129.20.0.0/16
129.26.0.0/15
129.31.0.0/16
129.67.0.0/16
129.69.0.0/16
129.70.0.0/16
129.73.0.0/16
129.88.0.0/16
129.102.0.0/15
129.104.0.0/16
129.125.0.0/16
129.129.0.0/16
129.132.0.0/16
129.142.0.0/15
129.169.0.0/16
129.175.0.0/16
129.177.0.0/16
129.178.0.0/16
129.181.0.0/16
129.182.0.0/15
129.184.0.0/15
129.187.0.0/16
129.194.0.0/15
129.199.0.0/16
129.206.0.0/16
129.208.0.0/16
129.214.0.0/16
129.215.0.0/16
129.217.0.0/16
129.233.0.0/16
129.234.0.0/16
129.240.0.0/15
129.242.0.0/16
129.247.0.0/16
# NET 130
130.0.0.0/16
130.24.0.0/16
130.25.0.0/16
130.26.0.0/16
130.28.0.0/16
130.32.0.0/16
130.37.0.0/16
130.43.0.0/16
130.59.0.0/16
130.60.0.0/16
130.66.0.0/15
130.73.0.0/16
130.75.0.0/16
130.78.0.0/15
130.82.0.0/15
130.84.0.0/16
130.88.0.0/15
130.92.0.0/16
130.93.0.0/16
130.98.0.0/16
130.100.0.0/16
130.104.0.0/16
130.112.0.0/16
130.115.0.0/16
130.120.0.0/16
130.125.0.0/16
130.133.0.0/16
130.136.0.0/16
130.138.0.0/15
130.140.0.0/14
130.144.0.0/14
130.148.0.0/15
130.159.0.0/16
130.161.0.0/16
130.164.128.0/17
130.180.0.0/16
130.183.0.0/16
130.185.0.0/16
130.186.0.0/16
130.188.0.0/16
130.190.0.0/16
130.192.0.0/16
130.193.0.0/16
130.198.0.0/16
130.204.0.0/16
130.206.0.0/16
130.208.0.0/15
130.223.0.0/16
130.225.0.0/16
130.226.0.0/15
130.228.0.0/14
130.232.0.0/13
130.240.0.0/14
130.244.0.0/16
130.246.0.0/16
130.251.0.0/16
130.255.0.0/16
# NET 131
131.1.0.0/16
131.97.0.0/16
131.99.0.0/16
131.102.0.0/16
131.111.0.0/16
131.114.0.0/15
131.116.0.0/15
131.130.0.0/16
131.152.0.0/16
131.154.0.0/15
131.159.0.0/16
131.160.0.0/16
131.164.0.0/15
131.166.0.0/16
131.169.0.0/16
131.173.0.0/16
131.174.0.0/15
131.176.0.0/15
131.180.0.0/16
131.188.0.0/16
131.205.0.0/16
131.207.0.0/16
131.211.0.0/16
131.220.0.0/16
131.224.0.0/16
131.227.0.0/16
131.228.0.0/16
131.231.0.0/16
131.234.0.0/16
131.237.0.0/16
131.246.0.0/16
131.251.0.0/16
131.254.0.0/16
# NET 132
132.64.0.0/13
132.72.0.0/14
132.76.0.0/15
132.78.0.0/16
132.146.0.0/16
132.149.0.0/16
132.150.0.0/16
132.153.0.0/16
132.155.0.0/16
132.165.0.0/16
132.166.0.0/15
132.168.0.0/15
132.171.0.0/16
132.176.0.0/16
132.180.0.0/16
132.185.0.0/16
132.186.0.0/16
132.187.0.0/16
132.195.0.0/16
132.196.0.0/16
132.199.0.0/16
132.227.0.0/16
132.229.0.0/16
132.230.0.0/15
132.244.0.0/16
132.252.0.0/16
# NET 134
134.0.0.0/16
134.1.0.0/16
134.2.0.0/16
134.3.0.0/16
134.17.0.0/16
134.19.0.0/16
134.21.0.0/16
134.25.0.0/16
134.27.0.0/16
134.28.0.0/16
134.30.0.0/16
134.34.0.0/16
134.35.0.0/16
134.36.0.0/16
134.37.0.0/16
134.47.0.0/16
134.54.0.0/16
134.58.0.0/15
134.60.0.0/15
134.76.0.0/16
134.81.0.0/16
134.83.0.0/16
134.90.0.0/16
134.91.0.0/16
134.92.0.0/14
134.96.0.0/13
134.104.0.0/14
134.108.0.0/15
134.110.0.0/16
134.119.0.0/16
134.130.0.0/16
134.138.0.0/16
134.142.0.0/15
134.145.0.0/16
134.146.0.0/15
134.151.0.0/16
134.155.0.0/16
134.157.0.0/16
134.158.0.0/16
134.169.0.0/16
134.171.0.0/16
134.176.0.0/16
134.183.0.0/16
134.184.0.0/16
134.188.0.0/16
134.191.0.0/16
134.203.0.0/16
134.206.0.0/16
134.212.0.0/15
134.214.0.0/16
134.219.0.0/16
134.220.0.0/15
134.222.0.0/16
134.225.0.0/16
134.226.0.0/15
134.239.0.0/16
134.245.0.0/16
134.246.0.0/15
134.249.0.0/16
134.255.0.0/16
# NET 135
135.90.0.0/16
135.196.0.0/16
# NET 136
136.143.0.0/17
136.148.0.0/16
136.155.0.0/16
136.156.0.0/16
136.157.0.0/16
136.158.0.0/16
136.163.0.0/16
136.164.0.0/16
136.169.0.0/16
136.170.0.0/16
136.172.0.0/15
136.199.0.0/16
136.201.0.0/16
136.206.0.0/16
136.225.0.0/16
136.230.0.0/15
136.243.0.0/16
136.255.0.0/16
# NET 137
137.17.0.0/16
137.33.0.0/16
137.34.0.0/16
137.43.0.0/16
137.44.0.0/16
137.47.0.0/16
137.50.0.0/16
137.55.0.0/16
137.56.0.0/16
137.58.0.0/16
137.60.0.0/15
137.62.0.0/16
137.73.0.0/16
137.74.0.0/16
137.93.0.0/16
137.96.0.0/16
137.101.0.0/16
137.105.0.0/16
137.108.0.0/16
137.120.0.0/15
137.129.0.0/16
137.133.0.0/16
137.138.0.0/16
137.156.0.0/16
137.163.0.0/16
137.174.0.0/16
137.191.0.0/16
137.193.0.0/16
137.194.0.0/15
137.204.0.0/15
137.208.0.0/16
137.213.0.0/16
137.217.0.0/16
137.218.0.0/16
137.221.0.0/16
137.222.0.0/15
137.224.0.0/16
137.226.0.0/16
137.248.0.0/16
137.250.0.0/15
137.253.0.0/16
# NET 138
138.3.0.0/16
138.4.0.0/16
138.6.0.0/16
138.14.0.0/16
138.21.0.0/16
138.22.0.0/16
138.37.0.0/16
138.38.0.0/16
138.40.0.0/15
138.48.0.0/16
138.62.0.0/15
138.66.0.0/16
138.70.0.0/16
138.81.0.0/16
138.96.0.0/16
138.100.0.0/16
138.102.0.0/16
138.103.0.0/16
138.104.0.0/16
138.106.0.0/16
138.124.0.0/16
138.131.0.0/16
138.132.0.0/16
138.134.0.0/16
138.187.0.0/16
138.188.0.0/14
138.195.0.0/16
138.198.0.0/15
138.200.0.0/15
138.203.0.0/16
138.205.0.0/16
138.206.0.0/16
138.215.0.0/16
138.216.0.0/16
138.221.0.0/16
138.222.0.0/15
138.224.0.0/14
138.228.0.0/16
138.231.0.0/16
138.232.0.0/15
138.244.0.0/15
138.246.0.0/16
138.248.0.0/14
138.253.0.0/16
# NET 139
139.1.0.0/16
139.2.0.0/15
139.4.0.0/16
139.6.0.0/15
139.8.0.0/16
139.10.0.0/15
139.12.0.0/14
139.16.0.0/13
139.24.0.0/15
139.27.0.0/16
139.28.0.0/15
139.30.0.0/16
139.45.0.0/16
139.47.0.0/16
139.50.0.0/16
139.54.0.0/16
139.58.0.0/16
139.63.0.0/16
139.64.0.0/17
139.66.0.0/16
139.74.0.0/15
139.79.0.0/16
139.83.0.0/16
139.89.0.0/16
139.90.0.0/15
139.92.0.0/16
139.96.0.0/15
139.98.0.0/16
139.100.0.0/16
139.105.0.0/16
139.106.0.0/15
139.108.0.0/14
139.112.0.0/13
139.120.0.0/16
139.122.0.0/15
139.124.0.0/16
139.128.0.0/16
139.133.0.0/16
139.141.0.0/16
139.143.0.0/16
139.145.0.0/16
139.149.0.0/16
139.153.0.0/16
139.156.0.0/16
139.157.0.0/16
139.158.0.0/16
139.160.0.0/16
139.162.0.0/16
139.164.0.0/15
139.166.0.0/16
139.174.0.0/16
139.178.0.0/15
139.184.0.0/16
139.191.0.0/16
139.222.0.0/16
# NET 140
140.77.0.0/16
140.78.0.0/16
140.84.0.0/15
140.86.0.0/16
140.93.0.0/16
140.94.0.0/16
140.97.0.0/16
140.105.0.0/16
140.150.0.0/15
140.164.0.0/16
140.166.0.0/16
140.181.0.0/16
140.203.0.0/16
140.231.0.0/16
# NET 142
142.154.0.0/17
142.247.0.0/16
# NET 143
143.41.0.0/16
143.47.0.0/16
143.50.0.0/15
143.52.0.0/15
143.65.0.0/16
143.92.128.0/17
143.93.0.0/16
143.97.0.0/16
143.99.0.0/16
143.117.0.0/16
143.118.0.0/16
143.121.0.0/16
143.126.0.0/16
143.129.0.0/16
143.130.0.0/16
143.161.0.0/16
143.163.0.0/16
143.164.0.0/16
143.167.0.0/16
143.169.0.0/16
143.176.0.0/14
143.180.0.0/16
143.196.0.0/16
143.205.0.0/16
143.210.0.0/16
143.217.0.0/16
143.224.0.0/15
143.233.0.0/16
143.234.0.0/16
143.237.0.0/16
143.239.0.0/16
143.245.0.0/16
143.252.0.0/16
# NET 144
144.2.0.0/16
144.4.0.0/16
144.20.0.0/15
144.24.0.0/16
144.27.0.0/16
144.32.0.0/16
144.41.0.0/16
144.43.0.0/16
144.44.0.0/16
144.48.60.0/22
144.54.0.0/16
144.56.0.0/15
144.63.0.0/16
144.64.0.0/15
144.76.0.0/16
144.82.0.0/16
144.84.0.0/15
144.86.0.0/17
144.87.0.0/16
144.95.0.0/16
144.98.0.0/16
144.119.0.0/16
144.122.0.0/16
144.124.0.0/16
144.127.0.0/16
144.145.0.0/16
144.164.0.0/15
144.173.0.0/16
144.176.0.0/14
144.180.0.0/15
144.193.0.0/16
144.200.0.0/16
144.204.0.0/16
144.206.0.0/16
144.208.0.0/18
144.209.0.0/16
144.248.0.0/16
# NET 146
146.0.0.0/16
146.2.0.0/15
146.4.0.0/16
146.19.0.0/16
146.21.0.0/16
146.48.0.0/16
146.50.0.0/16
146.52.0.0/16
146.59.0.0/16
146.60.0.0/16
146.66.0.0/16
146.67.0.0/16
146.70.0.0/16
146.72.0.0/16
146.75.0.0/16
146.77.0.0/16
146.80.0.0/15
146.87.0.0/16
146.90.0.0/16
146.97.0.0/16
146.100.0.0/14
146.104.0.0/14
146.108.0.0/15
146.110.0.0/16
146.112.0.0/16
146.119.0.0/16
146.120.0.0/16
146.124.0.0/16
146.133.0.0/16
146.136.0.0/16
146.140.0.0/16
146.158.0.0/16
146.159.0.0/16
146.161.0.0/16
146.162.0.0/16
146.169.0.0/16
146.172.0.0/15
146.175.0.0/16
146.176.0.0/15
146.179.0.0/16
146.185.0.0/16
146.188.0.0/16
146.191.0.0/16
146.192.0.0/15
146.194.0.0/16
146.210.0.0/15
146.212.0.0/16
146.213.0.0/16
146.216.0.0/16
146.219.0.0/16
146.220.0.0/16
146.224.0.0/16
146.227.0.0/16
146.228.0.0/16
146.234.0.0/16
146.241.0.0/16
146.247.0.0/16
146.248.0.0/15
146.251.0.0/16
146.253.0.0/16
146.254.0.0/16
146.255.0.0/16
# NET 147
147.7.0.0/16
147.12.0.0/15
147.14.0.0/16
147.27.0.0/16
147.28.0.0/16
147.29.0.0/16
147.30.0.0/16
147.32.0.0/15
147.44.0.0/15
147.52.0.0/16
147.54.0.0/16
147.60.0.0/16
147.67.0.0/16
147.68.0.0/16
147.75.0.0/16
147.77.0.0/16
#147.78.0.0/16
147.82.0.0/16
147.83.0.0/16
147.84.0.0/16
147.86.0.0/15
147.88.0.0/15
147.91.0.0/16
147.93.0.0/16
147.94.0.0/15
147.96.0.0/16
147.98.0.0/15
147.100.0.0/16
147.102.0.0/16
147.111.0.0/16
147.112.0.0/16
147.119.0.0/16
147.122.0.0/15
147.125.0.0/16
147.127.0.0/16
147.135.128.0/17
147.142.0.0/15
147.147.0.0/16
147.148.0.0/14
147.152.0.0/16
147.156.0.0/16
147.161.0.0/16
147.162.0.0/15
147.167.0.0/16
147.171.0.0/16
147.172.0.0/15
147.175.0.0/16
147.180.0.0/15
147.184.0.0/16
147.186.0.0/16
147.188.0.0/15
147.193.0.0/16
147.196.0.0/15
147.201.0.0/16
147.204.0.0/16
147.210.0.0/16
147.213.0.0/16
147.214.0.0/15
147.220.0.0/16
147.228.0.0/14
147.232.0.0/14
147.236.0.0/15
147.243.0.0/16
147.250.0.0/15
147.252.0.0/16
# NET 148
148.2.0.0/15
148.6.0.0/16
148.54.0.0/16
148.56.0.0/16
148.60.0.0/16
148.63.0.0/16
148.69.0.0/16
148.71.0.0/16
148.79.0.0/16
148.81.0.0/16
148.82.0.0/15
148.88.0.0/16
148.110.0.0/16
148.111.0.0/16
148.118.0.0/15
148.120.0.0/14
148.135.0.0/16
148.136.0.0/16
148.138.0.0/16
148.140.0.0/16
148.143.0.0/16
148.148.0.0/16
148.151.0.0/16
148.160.0.0/16
148.169.0.0/16
148.176.0.0/16
148.181.0.0/16
148.185.0.0/16
148.187.0.0/16
148.196.0.0/15
148.198.0.0/16
148.200.0.0/16
148.251.0.0/16
148.252.0.0/15
# NET 149
149.0.0.0/16
149.3.0.0/16
149.27.0.0/16
149.49.0.0/16
149.59.0.0/16
149.62.0.0/16
149.81.0.0/16
149.90.0.0/16
149.109.0.0/16
149.126.0.0/16
149.132.0.0/15
149.134.0.0/16
149.139.0.0/16
149.140.0.0/16
149.146.0.0/16
149.147.0.0/16
149.148.0.0/16
149.153.0.0/16
149.154.0.0/16
149.155.0.0/16
149.156.0.0/15
149.170.0.0/16
149.172.0.0/16
149.177.0.0/16
149.178.0.0/15
149.180.0.0/14
149.184.0.0/13
149.192.0.0/14
149.196.0.0/15
149.200.0.0/16
149.201.0.0/16
149.202.0.0/15
149.204.0.0/14
149.208.0.0/15
149.210.0.0/16
149.211.0.0/16
149.212.0.0/14
149.216.0.0/13
149.224.0.0/13
149.232.0.0/15
149.235.0.0/16
149.236.0.0/14
149.240.0.0/13
149.249.0.0/16
149.250.0.0/15
149.254.0.0/16
149.255.0.0/16
# NET 152
152.66.0.0/16
152.71.0.0/16
152.73.0.0/16
152.77.0.0/16
152.78.0.0/16
152.81.0.0/16
152.88.0.0/15
152.90.0.0/16
152.93.0.0/16
152.94.0.0/15
152.96.0.0/16
152.105.0.0/16
152.114.0.0/15
152.134.0.0/16
152.143.0.0/16
152.150.0.0/16
152.152.0.0/16
# NET 155
155.4.0.0/16
155.45.0.0/16
155.54.0.0/15
155.56.0.0/16
155.66.0.0/16
155.73.0.0/16
155.105.0.0/16
155.131.0.0/16
155.132.0.0/15
155.136.0.0/15
155.138.64.0/18
155.140.0.0/16
155.145.0.0/16
155.158.0.0/16
155.185.0.0/16
155.192.0.0/16
155.198.0.0/16
155.202.0.0/16
155.204.0.0/16
155.207.0.0/16
155.209.0.0/16
155.210.0.0/16
155.223.0.0/16
155.227.0.0/16
155.228.0.0/16
155.231.0.0/16
155.245.0.0/16
155.249.0.0/16
155.250.0.0/16
155.253.0.0/16
# NET 156
156.10.0.0/16
156.14.0.0/16
156.17.0.0/16
156.18.0.0/16
156.25.0.0/16
156.28.0.0/16
156.35.0.0/16
156.43.0.0/16
156.48.0.0/15
156.51.0.0/16
156.52.0.0/16
156.54.0.0/16
156.58.0.0/16
156.61.0.0/16
156.67.0.0/16
156.83.0.0/16
156.106.0.0/16
156.114.0.0/15
156.116.0.0/16
156.118.0.0/16
156.133.0.0/16
156.135.0.0/16
156.148.0.0/16
156.150.0.0/16
# NET 157
157.23.0.0/16
157.24.0.0/14
157.28.0.0/15
157.83.0.0/16
157.84.0.0/16
157.88.0.0/16
157.94.0.0/16
157.96.0.0/16
157.97.0.0/16
157.99.0.0/16
157.124.0.0/15
157.129.0.0/16
157.136.0.0/16
157.138.0.0/16
157.140.0.0/16
157.144.0.0/16
157.157.0.0/16
157.158.0.0/15
157.161.0.0/16
157.162.0.0/15
157.164.0.0/16
157.167.0.0/16
157.168.0.0/15
157.171.0.0/16
157.172.0.0/15
157.177.0.0/16
157.180.0.0/15
157.186.0.0/16
157.190.0.0/16
157.193.0.0/16
157.200.0.0/16
157.203.0.0/16
157.228.0.0/16
157.231.0.0/16
157.236.0.0/15
157.243.0.0/16
157.247.0.0/16
157.249.0.0/16
# NET 158
158.36.0.0/14
158.41.0.0/16
158.42.0.0/15
158.46.0.0/16
158.47.0.0/16
158.49.0.0/16
158.50.0.0/16
158.58.0.0/16
158.60.0.0/16
158.64.0.0/16
158.66.0.0/16
158.67.0.0/16
158.75.0.0/16
158.90.0.0/16
158.92.0.0/16
158.94.0.0/16
158.99.0.0/16
158.102.0.0/16
158.105.0.0/16
158.109.0.0/16
158.110.0.0/16
158.112.0.0/16
158.119.0.0/16
158.124.0.0/14
158.129.0.0/16
158.131.0.0/16
158.133.0.0/16
158.143.0.0/16
158.146.128.0/20
158.148.0.0/16
158.149.0.0/16
158.150.0.0/16
158.152.0.0/16
158.156.0.0/16
158.162.0.0/16
158.166.0.0/15
158.168.0.0/15
158.172.0.0/14
158.176.0.0/14
158.180.0.0/16
158.181.0.0/16
158.190.0.0/15
158.192.0.0/14
158.196.0.0/15
158.216.0.0/16
158.218.0.0/16
158.220.0.0/16
158.223.0.0/16
158.225.0.0/16
158.226.0.0/15
158.230.0.0/15
158.232.0.0/15
158.234.0.0/16
158.248.0.0/15
158.250.0.0/16
158.255.0.0/16
# NET 159
159.0.0.0/16
159.7.0.0/16
159.8.0.0/16
159.12.0.0/16
159.15.0.0/16
159.20.0.0/16
159.22.0.0/15
159.25.0.0/16
159.29.0.0/16
159.30.0.0/15
159.34.0.0/16
159.38.0.0/16
159.46.0.0/16
159.50.0.0/15
159.58.0.0/16
159.60.0.0/16
159.69.0.0/16
159.72.0.0/16
159.81.0.0/16
159.84.0.0/16
159.86.0.0/16
159.92.0.0/15
159.95.0.0/16
159.100.0.0/15
159.103.0.0/16
159.104.0.0/16
159.107.0.0/16
159.109.0.0/16
159.114.0.0/16
159.122.0.0/16
159.130.0.0/16
159.134.0.0/16
159.144.0.0/16
159.146.0.0/16
159.147.0.0/16
159.148.0.0/15
159.151.0.0/16
159.152.0.0/16
159.154.0.0/16
159.156.0.0/16
159.160.0.0/16
159.162.0.0/16
159.167.0.0/16
159.168.0.0/16
159.170.0.0/15
159.173.0.0/16
159.179.0.0/16
159.180.0.0/16
159.190.0.0/16
159.193.0.0/16
159.194.0.0/15
159.197.0.0/16
159.200.0.0/16
159.205.0.0/16
159.210.0.0/16
159.213.0.0/16
159.216.0.0/15
159.219.0.0/16
159.224.0.0/16
159.232.0.0/16
159.236.0.0/15
159.239.0.0/16
159.241.0.0/16
159.244.0.0/15
159.253.0.0/16
159.254.0.0/16
159.255.0.0/16
# NET 160
160.5.0.0/16
160.6.0.0/16
160.8.0.0/15
160.38.0.0/16
160.40.0.0/16
160.44.0.0/14
160.48.0.0/12
160.66.0.0/15
160.68.0.0/16
160.70.0.0/15
160.75.0.0/16
160.78.0.0/16
160.80.0.0/16
160.85.0.0/16
160.92.0.0/16
160.97.0.0/16
160.98.0.0/15
160.100.0.0/16
160.103.0.0/16
160.104.0.0/16
160.114.0.0/16
160.180.0.0/16
160.210.0.0/15
160.213.0.0/16
160.214.0.0/16
160.216.0.0/14
160.220.0.0/15
160.228.0.0/16
160.231.64.0/18
# NET 161
161.2.0.0/15
161.4.0.0/15
161.8.0.0/15
161.12.0.0/16
161.17.0.0/16
161.20.0.0/16
161.23.0.0/16
161.27.0.0/16
161.30.0.0/16
161.37.0.0/16
161.41.0.0/16
161.42.0.0/16
161.48.0.0/16
161.52.0.0/15
161.54.0.0/16
161.59.0.0/16
161.62.0.0/16
161.67.0.0/16
161.70.0.0/16
161.71.0.0/16
161.72.0.0/15
161.74.0.0/16
161.76.0.0/16
161.78.0.0/16
161.83.0.0/16
161.84.0.0/14
161.88.0.0/14
161.92.0.0/16
161.104.0.0/15
161.106.0.0/16
161.110.0.0/15
161.112.0.0/16
161.116.0.0/16
161.134.0.0/16
161.147.0.0/16
161.156.0.0/16
161.158.0.0/16
161.202.0.0/16
161.218.0.0/16
161.230.0.0/16
161.251.0.0/16
161.252.0.0/16
# NET 162
162.11.0.0/16
162.13.0.0/16
162.21.0.0/16
162.23.0.0/16
162.25.0.0/16
162.26.0.0/16
162.38.0.0/16
162.86.0.0/16
162.133.0.0/16
162.142.128.0/17
# NET 164
164.0.0.0/16
164.1.0.0/16
164.2.0.0/15
164.4.0.0/14
164.8.0.0/13
164.16.0.0/12
164.32.0.0/13
164.40.0.0/16
164.48.0.0/16
164.59.0.0/16
164.60.0.0/15
164.81.0.0/16
164.93.128.0/17
164.126.0.0/16
164.127.0.0/16
164.128.0.0/12
164.177.0.0/16
164.215.0.0/16
# NET 165
165.78.0.0/16
165.114.0.0/16
165.192.0.0/16
165.218.0.0/16
165.222.0.0/16
# NET 166
166.8.0.0/13
166.49.128.0/17
166.87.0.0/16
# NET 167
167.81.0.0/16
167.87.0.0/16
167.98.0.0/16
167.111.0.0/16
167.160.0.0/19
167.168.0.0/16
167.172.0.0/16
167.203.0.0/16
167.233.0.0/16
# NET 168
168.1.0.0/16
168.139.0.0/16
168.149.0.0/17
168.187.0.0/16
# NET 169
169.32.0.0/11
169.148.0.0/17
# NET 170
170.17.128.0/17
170.60.0.0/16
170.101.128.0/17
170.133.0.0/18
170.133.64.0/18
170.236.0.0/15
170.255.0.0/16
# NET 172
172.80.128.0/17
172.241.0.0/21
172.255.0.0/20
# NET 192
192.15.0.0/16
192.35.0.0/20
192.35.16.0/22
192.36.0.0/15
192.38.0.0/16
192.42.113.0/24
192.42.114.0/23
192.42.116.0/22
192.42.120.0/21
192.42.128.0/22
192.42.132.0/24
192.44.0.0/24
192.49.0.0/16
192.51.0.0/20
192.52.0.0/19
192.52.32.0/20
192.52.48.0/23
192.52.50.0/24
192.66.0.0/16
192.68.0.0/20
192.68.16.0/22
192.70.0.0/18
192.70.64.0/19
192.70.96.0/20
192.70.112.0/22
192.70.116.0/23
192.70.118.0/24
192.71.0.0/16
192.83.0.0/18
192.83.64.0/19
192.83.96.0/22
192.83.100.0/24
192.87.0.0/16
192.89.0.0/16
192.93.0.0/16
192.98.0.0/16
192.106.0.0/16
192.109.0.0/19
192.109.32.0/21
192.109.40.0/22
192.109.44.0/24
192.113.0.0/16
192.114.0.0/15
192.116.0.0/15
192.118.0.0/16
192.121.0.0/16
192.125.0.0/16
192.130.0.0/16
192.134.0.0/16
#192.144.0.0/18
#192.145.0.0/17
192.162.0.0/16
192.164.0.0/15
192.166.0.0/16
192.167.0.0/16
192.176.0.0/16
192.194.0.0/16
192.199.16.0/20
# NET 198
198.11.0.0/22
```