# What are the subnets for RIPE NCC?

Tags: ip

I can get a list of subnets for my country, but I couldn't find any list for EUROPE. (or RIPE NCC). Where can I get a list of subnets used by ISP's in Europe?

Comment: http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xhtml

Comment: can you post this as answer? ThankS! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [IANA](http://www.iana.org/) maintains several lists of numbers, one is the current [IPv4 Address](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xml) space allocation.

Answer (score 1):

The IANA lists are only what they have assigned.  It is far from what is actually administered by the RIR's.  Especially the case of the RIPE NCC.

The RIR's have transferred large amounts of "legacy" address space between each other.  This is not typically reflected in the IANA lists.  As the space is still assigned to the original RIR from the IANA perspective.

Take a gander at this to get an idea of the extent.
[Blocking all RIPE Addresses in Server 2008?](https://serverfault.com/questions/333031/blocking-all-ripe-addresses-in-server-2008/963201#963201)